# Difference between two xml formats

Tags: xml

I have one input file like below

```
ID,MID,NAME
1,0,A
```

Converted to below xml

```
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <MID>1</MID>
        <NAME>1</NAME>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

But expecting is below (2nd format)

```
<Employees>
<Employee key="ID">1</Employee>
<Employee key="MID">0</Employee>
<Employee key="NAME">A</Employee>
</Employees>
```

My question is not about how to convert but want to know whats the difference between two formats? Giving same information. Can the xml created by me be consumed by the end user who is expecting the second format?

Comment: If you are using a SOAP service, then ask your customer for the WSDL specification.  If he is expecting XML there probably is a certain format he wants.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Can you please help me to understand the second xml format....? Is <Employee> is a namespace here ? what is key here, something like key:value pair...?

Comment: Not a namespace, just a tag with a `key` attribute defined, the problem there could appear if you add more than 1 employee.

Comment: The second disallows multiple employees, making the "Employees" element pointless.

Answer (score 2):

It might be the same information as far as you are concerned, but only you can know that. The two documents are not in any way equivalent. If a recipient is expecting one of these formats then they will not understand the other.